# Can you still get item drops by watching livestreams?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, twitch

Back in 2013 there was a Dreamhack steel series cs:go championship and you could earn items by watching cs:go matches on Twitch.

I was wondering if you could still earn items by watching matches and if so, which channels do this? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Aqade. Nice question, but do you think you could fix your punctuation for readability?

Comment: +1 for the context. Good to know others like to make sure others know why they are talking about.

Comment: There isn't a 100% answer I think.. It is still posstible yes and has be done several times but nobody knows if the organizers will do it again, how could we know?

Answer (score 2):

http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2013/11/7922/

The last time you could get drops by watching Twitch were for Katowice 2015. If they decided to do this again, I'm sure they will announce it on the blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can only get item drops that way during specific events.

In the past, they have only enabled such drops during the Valve sponsored 'CS:GO major tournaments'. These are the same tournaments that have the team stickers and pickem challenges.

To get the drops you need to watch the specific streams playing the tournament. These channels change depending on the event. In the past these tournaments have been hosted by various groups such as Dreamhack and ESL.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you link your Twitch.tv account to CS:GO, yes you can.

You can connect your Twitch.tv account to CS:GO by:

- Going [here](http://www.twitch.tv/settings/connections) while logged in to Twitch.tv on your browser and connect steam.
- Going to the `Streams` tab in the `Watch` menu and entering your Twitch and Steam account information.